# ¿Error en deserealizar un json?

Tags: json, spring-boot

estoy realizando una API de prestamo de libro con spring boot .Tengo 4 clases Persona,libro,AccionLibro(Aca se vera si es un prestamo,o devolucion),tipoAccion.

Persona:

```
       @Entity
    @Table(name = "persona")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
    public class Persona implements Serializable {
        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private Long id;
        @Column(nullable = false, length = 8)
        private int dni;
        @Column(nullable = false)
        private String name;
        @Column(nullable = false)
        private boolean isActivo = true;
        @JsonIgnore
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "persona", targetEntity = com.example.model.AccionLibro.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
        private List<AccionLibro> accionLibro;
}
```

Libro:

@Entity
@Table(name = "libro")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class Libro implements Serializable {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;
@Column(nullable = false)
private String title;
@Column(nullable = false)
private int cantidad;
@Column(nullable = false)
private boolean isActivo = true;
@JsonIgnore
@OneToMany(targetEntity = com.example.model.AccionLibro.class, mappedBy = "libro", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<AccionLibro> accionLibro;

public Libro() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}}
```

AccionLibro:

```
   @Entity
    @Table(name = "accionlibro")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" })
    public class AccionLibro implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private Long id;
        @JsonIgnore
        @ManyToOne(targetEntity = com.example.model.Persona.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        private Persona persona;

        @ManyToOne(targetEntity = com.example.model.Libro.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        private Libro libro;
        @JsonIgnore
        @ManyToOne(targetEntity = com.example.model.TipoAccion.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        private TipoAccion tipoAccion;
        @Column(nullable = false)
        private int cantidad;
        @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
        private LocalDate fechaAccion;}
```

TipoAccion:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tipoAccion")
public class TipoAccion implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private TipoAccionE tipoAccion;
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = com.example.model.AccionLibro.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "tipoAccion", cascade = {CascadeType.REFRESH,CascadeType.MERGE}, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<AccionLibro> accionLibro;


    public TipoAccion() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }}
```

El problema va cuando quiero agregar una nueva AccionLibro.
Controlador de AccionLibro.

@RestController
public class AccionController {
    @Autowired
    private AccionService service;

```
@PostMapping(value = "/prestamo/persona/{idPersona}", produces = "application/json", consumes = "application/json")
public boolean setAccionLibro(@RequestBody AccionLibro accionLibro,@PathVariable Long idPersona) {
    System.out.println(accionLibro);
    return this.service.setPrestamo(accionLibro,idPersona);
}}
```

el Json que envio.

```
{
  "libro": {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "NAda de NAda",
    "cantidad": 5,
    "activo": true
  },
  "cantidad": 1,
  "fechaAccion": null,
  "tipoAccion": {
    "id": 1
  }
}
```

Error que me sale:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Segun estaba viendo es que no se puede deserializar un array pero lo raro es que en mi clase AccionLibro no tengo ningun array.
Como podria solucionarlo?

Comment: `java.util.ArrayList` no es un "array", es una implementación de `java.util.List`

Comment: pero aun asi no tengo ninguna coleccion en mi clase.

Comment: @liryco ¿Pudiste resolverlo?

Comment: sigo buscando la solucion @Angel